How to filter an html href attribute using a Wordpress hook
The code example below only filters for content not html code. I would like to replace the logo name in the href attribute on a particular page. Is there a way to do that similar to the filter below.
function replace_text( $text ) {
    if( is_page(318) ) {
    $text=str_replace('Logo-pink', 'logo-restaurant', $text);
       }

return $text;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');

